# Zoom linear gradient with page zoom

Tags: css

I would like to have my gradient zoomed in with the text in a container.

The gradient now has white beneath the text and colour on the sides:
[image]

How can I make it so that the white part of the gradient is always beneath the text, when zoomed? This is the undesired result now:
[image]

I've tried

```css
body {
    background-attachment: scroll !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
}
```

and more, but i always get the same result.

[here](https://pastebin.com/AEbK1NVa) is all of my CSS.

Comment: Please could you extract just enough of your CSS and HTML to show the problem and make a working snippet out of it. I did glance at the paste bin but ( apart from the fact it insisted on showing some ads) there is CSS  there irrelevant to the focus this problem needs.

Comment: https://codepen.io/buster-2002/pen/mdwWVRJ?editors=1100
As you can see, the text is perfectly within the white part of the gradient background. I want it to always be in the white part of the gradient, even when the web page is resized

Comment: Thanks for putting up the codepen. How are you resizing the web page?

Comment: ctrl + and ctrl -

Comment: Thanks, I understand now, those controls are designed to zoom text. On say an IOS device, pinch zoom works as you want, ie the whole thing gets zoomed.